# Prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(t)}{n^2+t^2}$ is equivalent to $\frac{\pi \ell}{2n}$

Tags: integration, asymptotics

> Let $f\colon [0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $\lim_{+\infty} f(x)=\ell$.
>
> Consider $I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(t)}{n^2+t^2}\mathrm dt$
>
> Prove that $I_n$ is equivalent to $\frac{\pi \ell}{2n}$ when $n\to\infty$

I just can prove that $I_n$ is defined at $0$ and $\infty$ since $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(t)}{n^2+t^2}=\frac{f(0)}{n^2}$ and $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{f(t)}{n^2+t^2}=0$

But I don't know how to prove $I_n$ is equivalent to $\frac{\pi \ell}{2n}$. I thought about the function $\arctan$ but I can't find a proof.

Comment: By "equivalent" do you mean "convergent?"

Comment: No, equivalent. Landau/equivalent sense.

Comment: I mean equivalent, @SeanRoberson , $I_n$ is convegent to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I am assuming $\ell > 0$; $\ell = 0 $ would be an issue for the equivalent.*

First, $I_n$ is well-defined for any $n$, since $f$ is bounded (can you see why?) and thus the integrand is integrable by comparison to 
$\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{n^2+t^2}$.

Consider $a_n\stackrel{\rm def}{=} nI_n$.
We have
$$\begin{align}
 a_n &= \int_0^\infty \frac{n}{n^2+t^2} f(t)dt
= \frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+(t/n)^2} f(t)dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+u^2} f(nu)du = \int_0^\infty g_n(u)du
\end{align}$$
where $g_n\colon u\in[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $g_n(u) = \frac{f(nu)}{1+u^2}$.
Now, apply the [Dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) to this, noting that the pointwise limit of $(g_n)_n$ is the function $g$ with:
$
g(u) = \frac{\ell}{1+u^2} = \ell\arctan'(u)
$
and
$$
\int_0^\infty g(u)du = \frac{\pi\ell}{2}.
$$

Altogether, this shows $\lim_{n\to\infty} nI_n = \frac{\pi\ell}{2}$, i.e. $I_n{\displaystyle\operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty}}\frac{\pi\ell}{2n}$.